# How do I parametrise the hyperbola $xy = y^2 -1$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric, parametrization

This equation is actually the solution to the intersection of the two surfaces $z = x^2 - y^2$, and $z = x^2 + xy - 1$.

I am to parametrise the solution curve, which is noted in the title. A first attempt is below:

\begin{align}
z &= x^2 - y^2 = x^2 + xy - 1 &\\ 
\implies x^2 - y^2 &=  x^2 + xy - 1 &\\
-y^2 &= xy - 1 &\\
xy &= y^2 - 1
\end{align}

Now, to parametrise, i.e. $x = f(t)$, $y = f(t)$:
\begin{align}
xy &= y^2 - 1 &\\
x &= \frac{y^2 - 1}{y} &\\
&= y - \frac{1}{y}
\end{align}

Let $y = t \in \mathbb{R}\backslash0$, and hence we have:
\begin{cases}
x = t - \frac{1}{t} \\[2ex]
y = t
\end{cases}

Will that suffice? I think not; there must be something more.

Comment: Why do you think there's something more? With $t \neq 0$, all of your steps are reversible to give you your original equation.

Comment: You might want to check, as @JohnOmielan seems to suggest, that indeed the parametrization you found covers *all* points on the curve. As it stands, your argument only shows that all points of the form $(t-\frac{1}{t},t)$ are on the curve.

Comment: @Servaes, ahh, I get it. I'd have to add in a term for z in terms of t, too, because right now, I've lost the information for z...

Comment: You also seem to be missing a sign somewhere; the intersection points satisfy $xy=1-y^2$.

Comment: @Servaes You are correct. The line $-y^2 = xy - 1$ goes to $xy = y^2 - 1$ instead of $xy = -y^2 + 1$, or equivalently $xy = 1 - y^2$ as you state.